# C++: Get a variable from a function containing multiple variables

Tags: c++, function

I'm very new to C++, and I'm trying to figure out how to get a specific variable from a function that holds multiple variables.

So here I have a function called `userInput()` that prompts the user for 3 values. Then, the function gets called later multiple times to give each specific function the user inputted values. The problem is, the way I've tried to do it causes the whole `userInput()` function to repeat, which brings the output to ask for the values many times over (see below).

I know my code could be trimmed down quite a bit, but hey, I'm learning here. So any suggestions about any part are much appreciated. *[Code Review post here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31224/new-to-c-repeating-function-output), for reference.*

## Code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float countySalesTax(), stateSalesTax(), totalSales();
void userInput(), display();

int main()
{
    countySalesTax(), stateSalesTax(), totalSales(), display();
    return 0;
}

void userInput(float totalMonthlySales, float countyTaxRate, float stateTaxRate) // Not sure how to do multiple variables in a function
{
    cout << "Enter the Total Monthly Sales:\t";
    cin >> totalMonthlySales;
    cout << "Enter the County Tax Rate:\t";
    cin >> countyTaxRate;
    cout << "Enter the State Tax Rate:\t";
    cin >> stateTaxRate;
}

float countySalesTax()
{

    float countyTax;
    float totalMonthlySales, countyTaxRate, stateTaxRate;
    userInput(totalMonthlySales, countyTaxRate, stateTaxRate); // Trying to call variables from userInput function?     
    countyTax = totalMonthlySales * countyTaxRate;
    return countyTax;
}

float stateSalesTax()
{
    float stateTax;
    float totalMonthlySales, countyTaxRate, stateTaxRate;
    userInput(totalMonthlySales, countyTaxRate, stateTaxRate); // same
    stateTax = totalMonthlySales * stateTaxRate;
    return stateTax;
}

float totalSales()
{
    float totalSalesTax;
    float countyTax = countySalesTax();
    float stateTax = stateSalesTax();
    totalSalesTax = countyTax + stateTax;
    return totalSalesTax;
}

void display()
{
    float countyTax = countySalesTax();
    float stateTax = stateSalesTax();
    float totalSalesTax = totalSales();

    cout << "The amount of County Tax is\t" << countyTax << endl;
    cout << "The amount of State Tax is\t" << stateTax << endl;
    cout << "The amount of Total Sales Tax is\t" << totalSalesTax << endl;
}
```

## Output

```
1. Enter the Total Monthly Sales:  20000
2. Enter the County Tax Rate:   0.02
3. Enter the Total Monthly Sales:   20000
4. Enter the State Tax Rate:    0.04
5. Enter the Total Monthly Sales:   20000
6. Enter the County Tax Rate:   0.02
7. Enter the Total Monthly Sales:   20000
8. Enter the State Tax Rate:    0.04
[...etc...]
17. The amount of County Tax is 400
18. The amount of State Tax is  800
19. The total sales is  1200
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying that "a variable returns variables"? A variable doesn't return anything.

Comment: Also (from the title): you don't *call* variables.

Comment: When doing separate operations, do them on separate lines. Doing `countySalesTax(), stateSalesTax(), totalSales(), display()` is just plain *awkward*. Don't do this.

Comment: I'd also rearrange the functions to eliminate the forward declarations. Remember DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself! It makes maintenance a pain if you have to keep updating the forward declaration and your fellow programmers will curse you! Sometimes you can't help it though.

Comment: I don't see how the code you posted could produce the output in your example. It would work that way if `userInput()` took reference arguments, but not with ordinary value arguments.

Comment: @Barmar You're right. The output is from the code I had about 2 revisions ago, which can be seen at the Code Review link I have in my question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the concept you are missing is that you can pass values to functions. Just call `userInput` once and then pass the values entered to your other functions. Like this

```
float countySalesTax(float totalMonthlySales, float countyTaxRate);

int main()
{
    float totalMonthlySales, countyTaxRate, stateTaxRate;
    userInput(totalMonthlySales, countyTaxRate, stateTaxRate);
    float countryTax = countySalesTax(totalMonthlySales, countyTaxRate);
    float stateTax = stateSalesTax(totalMonthlySales, stateTaxRate);
    ...
    return 0;
}

void userInput(float& totalMonthlySales, float& countyTaxRate, float& stateTaxRate)
{
    cout << "Enter the Total Monthly Sales:\t";
    cin >> totalMonthlySales;
    cout << "Enter the County Tax Rate:\t";
    cin >> countyTaxRate;
    cout << "Enter the State Tax Rate:\t";
    cin >> stateTaxRate;
}


float countySalesTax(float totalMonthlySales, float countyTaxRate)
{
    float countyTax;
    countyTax = totalMonthlySales * countyTaxRate;
    return countyTax;
}


float stateSalesTax(float totalMonthlySales, float stateTaxRate)
{
    float stateTax;
    stateTax = totalMonthlySales * stateTaxRate;
    return stateTax;
}
```

The other thing wrong is that you must use *references* if you want to return multiple values from `userInput`, i.e. you must use `float&` not `float` for the parameters to `userInput`.

Comment: This is what I wanted to do. I had mistakenly thought that I had to call a function each time I wanted to use one of its variables (didn't know about references, either).

Answer (score 1):

1. You can define global variables and make changes to those variables in the function.
   Global variable are defined before main, and can be accessed anywhere.
2. You could have the function return an array of floats.
3. You can pass the floats in the function by reference and make changes to them which would be reflected outside the function. Change your userInput function to this:

   `userInput(float &totalMonthlySales, float &countyTaxRate, float &stateTaxRate)`

Answer (score 1):

Create a struct holding those 3 values.  userInput returns this struct of values, and the others are passed the struct

```
struct Input
{
    float  totalMonthlySales,
           countyTaxRate,
           stateTaxRate;
};

Input userInput()
{
    Input returnValue;

    cout << "Enter the Total Monthly Sales:\t";
    cin >> returnValue.totalMonthlySales;
    cout << "Enter the County Tax Rate:\t";
    cin >> returnValue.countyTaxRate;
    cout << "Enter the State Tax Rate:\t";
    cin >> returnValue.stateTaxRate;

    return returnValue;
}

void main()
{
    Input sharedInput = userInput();
    float countyTax = countySalesTax(sharedInput);
    float stateSalesTax = stateSalesTax(sharedInput);
    float totalSalesTax = totalSalesTax(sharedInput);
    display(countyTax, stateSalesTax, totalSalesTax);
}

float countySalesTax(Input inputData)
{

    float countyTax;
    countyTax = inputData.totalMonthlySales * inputData.countyTaxRate;
    return countyTax;
}
//... and so on
```

Others will recommend that you use "pass by reference" because it is more efficient than what I did, but it is the same pattern, with a few gotchas.  Once you understand this version, look up pass by reference to understand the more typical implementation

Comment: This is interesting. I haven't encountered the `struct` or `Input()` types yet (in my learning). I will keep this in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may be calling the functions too many times undesirably. Each time you write `countySalesTax()` there will be a function call, especially if you do `countyTax = countySalesTax()`. What you probably want to do is call each of these functions only once, you could do it in `main` and then pass what you find to other functions.

Notice that what you have in main currently calls the functions and the float they return is thrown away because it is not assigned.